# (Java) Error while sending and image through socket: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 3B

Tags: java, sockets, exception, stream

im making a bomberman game and it need to work in LAN. i need to send an image, 2 ints and an object from a client (the game) to a server, and back to another client (another game). Right now im just trying to send all those things forma a game, to the server and back to the game.The problem im having occurs when i try to send an image a second time. This is my code for the server part:

```
public class Server {
//Atributes....................................
private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;   
private Socket socket = null;

public boolean conected = false;

 private ObjectInputStream Mensajeinput = null;
 private ObjectOutputStream Mensajeoutput = null;

 private DataInputStream BomberInput = null;
 private DataOutputStream BomberOutput = null;
//.............................................

 int X, Y;
 BufferedImage CurrentSprite;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   Server Servidor = new Server();

   Servidor.run();
}

public void run() throws Exception{

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(208);     

        socket = serverSocket.accept();  


        conected=true;                                       
        Mensaje Actualization= null;                 

        while ( conected ){

            //=====initialize all the input and output Streams================================

              BomberInput = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
              BomberOutput = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

              Mensajeinput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
              Mensajeoutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

              //=====receive and send the ints ============

              X = (int) BomberInput.readInt();
              BomberOutput.writeInt(X);
              BomberOutput.flush();

              Y = (int) BomberInput.readInt();
              BomberOutput.writeInt(Y);
              BomberOutput.flush();


            //=========receieve and send the image===================== 
              CurrentSprite = (BufferedImage) ImageIO.read(BomberInput);
              ImageIO.write(CurrentSprite, "GIF", BomberOutput);

            //==========receive the object=================

              Actualization= (Mensaje) Mensajeinput.readObject();        

        }
        //====Close socket===============================
        socket.close();

  }
}
```

This is the Client part of the Game code:

```
  M = new Mensaje(0 , 0 , 0, 0);

                if (b1.isAlive()) controlPj.MoverPj(b1, M);


 //*****************************INTERACTION WITH THE SERVER*****************************                    
               //=====Initialize inputs and outputs=======

                 BomberOutput = new DataOutputStream(Sock.getOutputStream());
                 BomberInput = new DataInputStream(Sock.getInputStream());

                 MensajeOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(Sock.getOutputStream());
                 MensajeInput = new ObjectInputStream(Sock.getInputStream());

                //=====Sends and receive the ints =======  
                 BomberOutput.writeInt(b1.x);
                 X = BomberInput.readInt();
                 BomberOutput.flush();


                 BomberOutput.writeInt(b1.y);
                 Y = BomberInput.readInt();
                 BomberOutput.flush();

                 //======Sends and receive the image=======

                     ImageIO.write(b1.Current, "GIF",  BomberOutput );
                     EnemmySprite = (BufferedImage) ImageIO.read(BomberInput);

                 //======================Sends the object==================

                   MensajeOutput.writeObject(M);
                   MensajeOutput.flush();

                  System.out.println("Matriz Actualizada Recibida");
               //==========================================================================

//***********************************************************************************************************************
```

All works ok except for the image part. The client sends the image, the server receive it, and re-sends it and the client receive it. but then it throws this error:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 3B
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1379)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at bomberman2.Server.run(Server.java:90)
    at bomberman2.Server.main(Server.java:42)
```

the specific line where the error occurs is in

```
   Actualization= (Mensaje) Mensajeinput.readObject();
```

Any idea of why this error is happening? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where is line 90 in your source? There is no "readObject()" in it. Besides you should do the flush() before the read. If you do this single threaded it might lock-up otherwise.

Comment: There is an issue with use ImageIO.write in this way, instead, write the image to a ByteArrayOutputStream and then write the resulting byte[] to the Socket, or just read the bytes directly from the image file and write that

Comment: I would suggest structuring the client to contain all runtime images and the server be the adjudicator for game logic rather than frequently sending image data.

Comment: Get rid of the DataInput/OutputStreams and use the object streams for everything. Don't use multiple stream types on the same socket.